# AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'origin'

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, image, alpha, origin, x, y):
        self.image = image
        if alpha: self.surface = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
        else: self.surface = pygame.image.load(image).convert()
        self.rectangle = self.surface.get_rect(origin = (x, y))

    def setpos(self, x, y):
        self.rectangle.x = x
        self.rectangle.y = y

    def place(self):
        screen.blit(self.surface, self.rectangle)

test = Rectangle('image.png', 1, 'midtop', 0, 0)
```

I want to input the origin, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object has a lot of virtual attributes, however `origin` is not one of them. `topleft` or `center`, on the other hand, is:

```py
self.rectangle = self.surface.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
```

```py
self.rectangle = self.surface.get_rect(center = (x, y))
```